# node.js / Socket.timeout(number)

Tags: node.js

I wrote the next code:

```
socket.setTimeout(2000);
socket.on('timeout', function() {   
    console.log("Timeout");
});
    socket.on('data', function(data){})
```

I send a data to my socket, but when I finish to send this data, the timeout doesn't occuer.

There is no socket.end() in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to pass the timeout callback as a method straight to setTimeout where it will be added as a one-time listener to `'timeout'`;

```js
socket.setTimeout(2000, function() {  
    console.log("Timeout");
});
socket.on('data', function(data){})
```

I've never seen the syntax of listening to the `''` event before (I probably missed something), but the event for a timeout if you want to listen with it using `on` should be called `'timeout'`.

Comment: Yes, I correct the last issue. I try your idea, but its still the same.

Comment: @user2450886 Sounds like there may be something not showing in your displayed code that's preventing the event from triggering. Sadly hard to debug then :-/

Comment: There is other command which close the socket besides socket.end() and socket.destroy()? As I understand, socket.write doesn't close the socket.

Comment: @user2450886 No, it shouldn't close unless there's an error transmitting the data, in which the error handler should be invoked.